# How can I redirect folders to pages in IIS?

Tags: wordpress, redirect, iis, url-rewriting

We're moving from a wordpress setup to a static site and we don't want all our pages to be index pages of a folder... but some pages will need to be index of a folder - I'm struggling on how we'll be able to do this without doing it manually, we have over 7000 pages.

If possible we'd like to redirect URLs like this:

```
domain.com/section1/
domain.com/section2/section/
domain.com/section3/section/section
```

to URLS like this:

```
domain.com/section1.html
domain.com/section2/section.html
domain.com/section3/section/section.html
```

but then we'll need to manually redirect/override specific URLS like `domain.com/section2/section.html` to be `domain.com/section2/section/index.html`

to top that off, we'd like to not show the .html on our URLs...

We just don't want our system/pages to all be index pages in folders but we do want that URL structure.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve such an override?

`domain.com/section2/section -> domain.com/section2/section/index`

If yes, you can refer to the following rule:

```
<rule name="test1" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}/index" />
</rule>
```

if not, please post more details information about your requirement.